# How to make a dynamic paint brush from a fluid domain so fluid sticks on effector objects like paint?

Tags: animation, physics, texture-painting, fluid-simulation, dynamic-paint

### Problem

Hi! I'm trying to make a paint splatter that gets thrown on an effector with many polygons, and lets the color of the paint stick to the surface it touches based on it's shape, cause that's how paint reacts in real life. All the youtube videos I've watched only use flat surfaces, and none of it is working.

### How to repeat this problem

I have a `fluid domain`, which is also a `dynamic paint brush`. I baked it, and the fluid mesh gets launched on an `effector`, which is also a `dynamic paint canvas`.

The fluid reacts to the effector / canvas properly, but there is no "paint" coloring it. It all just sloshes off like it was water, with no color difference.

All I did was bake the domain, the canvas too, and subdivided the monkey head because the [canvas says `vertex paint` needs many for it to work. *(found in format ---> vertex on that page)*.](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/physics/dynamic_paint/canvas.html#canvas)

I also tried an option where I used an image sequence from a baked canvas, but that wouldn't work either. Nothing shows up, and I have Cycles and the render viewport on.

Thanks!

### Blend file

Here: https://pasteall.org/media/b/3/b37c0b8562de1fd5ed911cf56267ee45.blend

Comment: is this [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qdMLN.gif what you want to achieve?

Comment: Yes, but when I look at the eye area on the right of that gif, it's not changing color like the other side is, even though it's getting the full force of the paint. Also, the material on the domain *(paint)* I'll be using will also blend with the object being hit, so I think I'll use a `MixRGB` for that. Unless there's some other requirement for that?